# Do spammers or spambots clicking AdWords ads?

Tags: spam, google-ads, clicks

One of my sites has a very high bounce rate from Google AdWords, especially over the last couple of days.

Of course, it could just be that people are not finding the site relevant.

But I'm wondering if it could be spambots or something like this.

Can spambots click Google AdWords ads?

Or do human spammers tend to click AdWords ads to find places to spam?

Answer (score 2):

> Can spambots click Google Adwords ads?

At least [one](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2004/06/25/google_adwords_blackmail/) person is in jail for trying it (or, more accurately, trying to blackmail Google because he'd figured out how to do it).

Automated clicks remain a concern and Google claims to be able to prevent this type of spam, though it is an arms race which Google does not have a keen incentive to dominate (Google gets paid whether or not the clicks are legitimate).

> Or do human spammers tend to click Adwords ads to find places to spam?

Human spammers tend to run scripts to automate their spamming efforts - with the exception of outsourced comment spammers, it is highly unlikely that a human is directly participating in any commercially-motivated spamming efforts.

Comment: Thanks danlefree. Is there a way to judge whether the clicks are likely to be automated / from a spam bot? The clicks are from quite a few different countries -- they're not all from the same location -- might that, for example indicate it's not a spam bot? But on the other hand, all the clicks so far today are 100% bounce; 0 time on the site; and 1 pages/visit

Comment: As the recipient of the clicks, you might look for similarities between bounces (I recall a client who identified [FunWebProducts](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum81/5136.htm) as a source of click spam in 2004) but a professional operation (proxy network or distributed malware) wouldn't provide you with any indicators you could pin down - prevention falls to Google. Perhaps the money you're spending with Adwords would be better spent with a more conventional form of advertising or on building organic rankings?

Answer (score 0):

It is not only for you, If you look at the analytic of Your website, Organic traffic will have less bounce rate, then comes the referral or direct traffic based on your marketing methods.

But mostly the paid traffic tend to have more bounce rate mainly due to targeting incorrect audience and certainly Adword sends more invalid traffic may not be from spammer. But for those invalid clicks, you are paying to adwords.

**Some examples of invalid click for which you are paying**

- Click from your competitors
- Click from your SEO people, who analyse the top ranking Ads
- Click from keyword researchers who clicks on the Ad
- Click from analyst who clicks on your Ads without having any indention of doing business with you

I am very confident that, You could be paying at least for 20% ~ 25% clicks which are not valid. (may not be from spammers)